# Reliable way to open a group of URLs using Google Chrome on Windows 10 from the command line (batch or powershell)

Tags: windows-10, command-line, google-chrome, powershell

My code snippet (Windows 10 cmd shell)

```
set s1="https://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/programmes/schedules#on-now" 
set s2="https://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4extra/programmes/schedules#on-now" 
set s3="https://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/guide"
set s4="http://192.168.1.33:1935"
start  chrome --new-tab %s1% %s2% %s3% %s4%
```

Sometimes this works. Other times, Chrome opens the first site and then pauses, or opens the first two and not the rest.

I would like a reliable way to do this that only uses either Windows cmd or PowerShell, without any kind of extensions or external tool.

Answer (score 1):

This worked quite nicely for me, in powershell:

```
$sites = @()

$sites += "https://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4/programmes/schedules#on-now" 
$sites += "https://www.bbc.co.uk/radio4extra/programmes/schedules#on-now" 
$sites += "https://www.bbc.co.uk/iplayer/guide"
$sites += "http://192.168.1.33:1935"

foreach($site in $sites){
start-process chrome.exe $site
}
```